# Create shapefile without coordinates

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, coordinates

I am trying to create a shapefile without XY coordinates.  I have the address, but not coordinates and there are too many entries to enter them manually.  I am then going to join that to another data set (also without coordinates), but with a corresponding column.

Is this possible/ how would I do this?

Comment: A shapefile without geometry is a dBase file. While shapefiles do support Null geometries, they're generally placeholders where *some* of the geometries are missing, not all. All in all, you'd be better off with CSV, JSON, or any modern database format before using early '80s XBase technology.

Comment: It sounds like you need address geocoding. You can research this. But you will likely need some skill in Excel or other data editor to get the fields put together or split apart. Geocoders can magically create points from addresses if you give them data in the right format. There are also some online options that take addresses and give you coordinates.